# MacOS M2 failing when installing Python mysqlclient library

Tags: python, mysql, macos, python-poetry

`pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for mysqlclient (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [43 lines of output]
mysql_config --version
['8.0.33']
mysql_config --libs
['-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/lib', '-lmysqlclient', '-lzlib', '-lzstd', '-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib', '-lssl', '-lcrypto', '-lresolv']
mysql_config --cflags
['-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/include/mysql']
ext_options:
library_dirs: ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/lib', '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib']
libraries: ['mysqlclient', 'zlib', 'resolv']
extra_compile_args: ['-std=c99']
extra_link_args: []
include_dirs: ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/include/mysql']
extra_objects: []
define_macros: [('version_info', "(2,1,1,'final',0)"), ('**version**', '2.1.1')]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/*exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/**init**.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb.*mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include -Dversion_info=(2,1,1,'final',0) -D__version**=2.1.1 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/include/mysql -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.33/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -lmysqlclient -lzlib -lresolv -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-310-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lzlib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

I was following guide from official repo https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient:

macOS (Homebrew)
Install MySQL and mysqlclient:

## Assume you are activating Python 3 venv

`$ brew install mysql $ pip install mysqlclient`

Instead of venv, i am using Poetry. I have tried also without any virtualenv and i have same issue.
Mysql is installed correctly and i can run it.

Answer (score 2):

[This issue was raised yesterday in the `mysqlclient` repository on GitHub](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/584).

GitHub user [`@methane`](https://github.com/methane) provided [a workaround](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/584#issuecomment-1537354773) by slightly modifying some environment variables using the [`pkg-config`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pkg-config) utility before installing that seem to have worked for others in a similar execution environment:

```
export MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --libs mysqlclient)
export MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags mysqlclient)
pip install mysqlclient
```